# Finding a matrix that represents a linear transformation with respect to a basis $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the matrix representing $f:K^3\rightarrow K^3$ such that $$f\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x+y+z\\x-y+z\\x+y-z\end{pmatrix}$$
with respect to the basis $W=[w_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},w_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},w_3=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}]$

note: We're considering the same basis as input, i.e. we're looking for the matrix $A$ such that $f(W)=WA$

My attempt:

I've computed $f(1,0,1),f(0,1,1),f(1,1,0)$ and written each of the results $(2,2,0),(2,0,0),(2,0,2)$ in terms of a linear combination of the three basis vectors, at this points I've written down the matrix having as $i$-th column the coefficients of the $w1,w2,w3$ in the representation of $f(w_i)$ getting:$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}&2\\0&-\frac{1}{2}&0\\2&\frac{1}{2}&0\end{pmatrix}$$
My textbook provides no examples nor solutions so I have no clue if what I did makes any sense, I just started studying linear algebra so I'd appreciate if anyone could work the problem out for me if my solution isn't correct, thanks

Comment: looks fine by me, tough i would change the middle column to $(1,-1,1)$

Comment: I have $(1,-1,1)^T$ as second column. The other two are ok.

Comment: @friedvir So how would I show that $WA$ is actually $f(W)$?

Comment: i think you bit missunderstood... f is a L.T, which define over a vector of three elements. the represntation means that when you take a vector from the dimension of $K^3$, it can be represent as linear combintaion of those three, and therfore, you asked to show what transformation does to every part of this vector... A is a matrix, that when you multiplier the vector by it, will give you tha same result as the definition of $f$. you can take any vector and see it for yourself